# understanding hashmap java syntax myMap.get().put()

Tags: java

I was going through the [following tutorials](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/31/loading-caching-and-displaying-images-in-android-part-1/) and I came across this code which I got stumped as to what it is doing:

```
while (true) { 

   if (myMap != null && myMap.get() != null) { 

     **myMap.get().put(i++, "test" + i);** 

     System.out.println("im still working!!!!");
```

I have no idewa waht myMap.get().put() does, can you explain to me ?

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc of `Map`?

Comment: What type is myMap? The base `Map` interface doesn't have a `get()` method, only `get(Object)`.

Comment: Also, your linked tutorial contains no such code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the actual type of `myMap` is [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).
And `get` method is invoked on a `WeakReference` instance returning a `Map`.